# How to setup IntelliJ + Scala + specs + sbt project?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, specs2, sbt-idea

I am trying to setup an empty sbt project with specs2 for Scala (2.10) with IntelliJ (12.1) support and I am getting this error when I do `sbt compile` on empty project directory:

```
% sbt compile                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Getting net.java.dev.jna jna 3.2.3 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-jna
    confs: [default]
    1 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (838kB/32ms)
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt_2.9.1 0.11.3 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
    confs: [default]
    37 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (7245kB/734ms)
Getting Scala 2.9.1 (for sbt)...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    4 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (19939kB/402ms)
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/pathikrit/Projects/scalgos/project
[info] Set current project to scalgos (in build file:/Users/pathikrit/Projects/scalgos/)
Getting Scala 2.10.1 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24386kB/107ms)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/pathikrit/Projects/scalgos/}default-7d65e1...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2_2.10.1;1.14 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.specs2#specs2_2.10.1;1.14
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/pathikrit/.ivy2/local/org.specs2/specs2_2.10.1/1.14/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/specs2/specs2_2.10.1/1.14/specs2_2.10.1-1.14.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.specs2#specs2_2.10.1;1.14: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/Users/pathikrit/Projects/scalgos/}default-7d65e1/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.specs2#specs2_2.10.1;1.14: not found
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Mar 25, 2013 5:11:17 PM
```

My `build.sbt` file looks like this:

```
name := "scalgos"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.14" % "test"
```

I installed sbt by doing `brew install sbt`:

```
% brew info sbt                                                                                                                                                                                   
sbt: stable 0.12.2, devel 0.13.0-M1
http://www.scala-sbt.org
/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.11.3-2 (3 files, 1.1M) *
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/sbt.rb
==> Caveats
You can use $SBT_OPTS to pass additional JVM options to SBT.
For convenience, this can specified in `~/.sbtconfig`.

For example:
    SBT_OPTS="-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
```

Brew says I have sbt 0.12 but when I `sbt --version` I get:

```
% sbt --version                                                                                                                                                                                    
sbt launcher version 0.11.3-2
```

I tried to atleast generate the IntelliJ files by putting this in my $PROJECT_DIR/projects/plugins.sbt:

```
resolvers += "sbt-idea-repo" at "http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.2.0")
```

But when I did `sbt gen-idea`, I got this error:

```
% sbt gen-idea                                                                                                                                                                                               
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/pathikrit/Projects/scalgos/project
[info] Set current project to scalgos (in build file:/Users/pathikrit/Projects/scalgos/)
[info] Trying to create an Idea module scalgos
[info] Updating {file:/Users/pathikrit/Projects/scalgos/}default-7d65e1...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2_2.10.1;1.14 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.specs2#specs2_2.10.1;1.14
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/pathikrit/.ivy2/local/org.specs2/specs2_2.10.1/1.14/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/specs2/specs2_2.10.1/1.14/specs2_2.10.1-1.14.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.specs2#specs2_2.10.1;1.14: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/Users/pathikrit/Projects/scalgos/}default-7d65e1/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.specs2#specs2_2.10.1;1.14: not found
[info] Updating {file:/Users/pathikrit/Projects/scalgos/}default-7d65e1...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2_2.10.1;1.14 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.specs2#specs2_2.10.1;1.14
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/pathikrit/.ivy2/local/org.specs2/specs2_2.10.1/1.14/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/specs2/specs2_2.10.1/1.14/specs2_2.10.1-1.14.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.specs2#specs2_2.10.1;1.14: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/Users/pathikrit/Projects/scalgos/}default-7d65e1/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.specs2#specs2_2.10.1;1.14: not found
[error] Failed to obtain dependency classpath
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Can someone post a sample `build.sbt` that would generate IntelliJ 12.1 files for Scala 2.10.1 and sbt?

I checked in my project here: https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos

Please advise what am I doing wrong???

Comment: I think brew agrees with your version of sbt: it says it's in /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/**0.11.3-2** . I'd update it to 0.12 and try again. Your project works fine for me with sbt 0.12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use this project i built that provides what you are looking for out of the box

[Skeleton](https://github.com/fractal/skeleton)

I'm planning to upgrade the sbt config and latest and greatest libs (sbt-idea 1.3.0 and scala 2.10.1) tonight.

enjoy!

Comment: Awesome, now I will fork your repo everytime I hack on Scala projects - probably good idea to populate with default main/src/scala/package/Hello.scala and test/src/scala/package/HelloSpec.scala? To tell you the truth, I am not a fan of this deep maven style project structure anyway...

Comment: I used to have tests, but then you actually had to delete them. See the updated build.sbt, it now pulls all latest libraries. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

you should update sbt version to 0.12.X, create file "project/build.properties", and put "sbt.version=0.12.1"

i forked your repo and edited the sbt version, it seems work fine on my machine

https://github.com/yuanw/scalgos

Comment: Thanks, it was some issue with brew not updating sbt to 0.12 correctly.